# JG not working as intended? (conditional branch)

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, dos

I'm trying to write a program that finds the larger of two variables and saves the answer in [largest].

This involves using branching conditions.

---

Here is my program:

```
; Find
; Gunner Stone ver 1.0 2/27/2017
;
org 100h
section .text
; beginning address of code = 0x0100
;*******************************************************
;
start:
    mov dl, [num1]
    cmp dl, [num2]
    jg assignA          ;should jump if dl is greater than [num2]
    mov dl, [num2]

assignA:
   mov   [largest], dl

infiniteLoop:
    jmp infiniteLoop
;       
;*******************************************************        
ILP:    JMP ILP             ;infinite loop
;
TIMES 50H -($-$$) DB 0
section .data
; beginning address of data = 0x0150
;*******************************************************
;
num1: db 0x0A
num2: db 0xFA
largest: db 00
;
;*******************************************************
```

My problem, or lack of understanding, is that even though [num1] is smaller than [num2], the jump triggers `jg assignA`.

If anyone can tell me why this is happening/where the flaw in my thinking is, that would help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the JG function treats both values [num1] and [num2] as **signed** integers.

[image]

If it were JA, **FA** would be larger than **0A**.

---

**0A**
0000 1010  *A positive number*

**FA** 1111 1010  *A negative number*

So 0A is in fact greater than FA

Comment: No, it's not the CMP instruction that treats them as signed values.

Comment: @RossRidge would you mind explaining more than just saying its not the CMP?

Comment: Because CMP can be used to compare both unsigned and signed values. It just sets flags which can be tested by a Jcc instruction like JG. The JG instruction tests that ZF is zero and that SF equals OF and jumps if both conditions are true. This happens to be what CMP sets the flags to when the first operand is greater than the second operand, interpreting both operands a signed integers. On the other hand, the JA instruction jumps if CF = 0 and ZF = 0, which is what the CMP instruction sets the flags to when the first operand is above the second, both operands being unsigned integers.